# Vaadin background-image setSize?

Tags: java, css, background-image, vaadin

currently I try to style a Vaadin project with css. I use:

```
.image-background {
        background-image: url("../resources/bilder/wallpaper1.jpg");
```

However the result was not as expected. The image has a resolution of 1920x1080px. But if I now put the website on a lower resolution screen I only see a part of the image. Is there a possibility using css to set the image fullsize of the screen?

Comment: You need to go have a look at the background image css properties. Simply typing `background image size css` into google should give you enough results such as this one (top of the page). https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 1):

**Vaadin part**

If running Spring Boot with Vaadin the place the background image in folder `src/main/resources/static`, and if not running Spring Boot then use `src/main/webapp` folder.

Then add required CSS to change the background. By default, Valo style will have a background color in div with class `v-ui`. You can use custom theme and override background through that or you can update style straight from code.

```
@SpringUI
public class MyUi extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        initBackground();
        initContent();
    }

    private void initBackground() {
        Page.getCurrent().getStyles().add(
                ".v-ui { background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;" +
                        "-webkit-background-size: cover;" +
                        "-moz-background-size: cover;" +
                        "-o-background-size: cover;" +
                        "background-size: cover; }"
        );
    }
...
```

**CSS part**

For CSS part you can check [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) or some other source. Actual solution depends a bit how you want to background image to behave.